# mPDF - get position of element

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Can I get current position (x,y) of element on page?

For example, I have this:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4', 9, 'Arial', 7, 7, 8, 18, 0, 6);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div id="audit_list"><table>');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr><td>Text 1</td></tr>');
var_dump($mpdf->y); // otput 8

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr><td>Text 2</td></tr>');
var_dump($mpdf->y); // otput 8

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr><td>Text 3</td></tr>');
var_dump($mpdf->y); // otput 8

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr><td>Text 4</td></tr>');
var_dump($mpdf->y); // otput 8

$mpdf->WriteHTML('</table></div>');
var_dump($mpdf->y); // otput 28.425833333333
```

Why is the output of the table elements `<tr><td>` always 8?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`$mpdf->x`

`$mpdf->y`

X = horizontal and Y = vertical

you can also use built-in methods if you have an older version of MPDF to make code clearer:

`$mpdf->GetX()`
`$mpdf->GetY()`

Comment: $mpdf->y returns me still the same number.  // 8

Comment: could you be clearer? not understanding the problem :)

Comment: If I use the variable ($pos = $mpdf->y), so variable "$pos" in cycle foreach has the same value. In this case, the value is "8".

Comment: update your original post and I will fix the code ;)

Comment: original post is fixed :)

Comment: Still unsure what you are trying to do with $posy, it should get the position before "</table></div>" at the end of the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still finds this question:
`mPDF` only updates `->y` after block level elements have been closed (like web browsers do), so `mpdf->y` stays at the initial 8 defined by page margins *until the full block level element gets rendered* after the final closing tab.

If you need to get intermediate y positions your best bet is to clone the `mPDF` object and do something like:

```
$my_mpdf_clone->WriteHTML('</table></div>');
var_dump($my_mpdf_clone->y);
unset($my_mpdf_clone);
```

Update: Please note also that elements with CSS position:absolute or position:fixed never update `mPDF`'s x/y cursor. If you need to get the width/height of these elements (temporarily) set style to `position:initial` first.

Here's a sample snipset to get the width/height of an html block:

```
// $mpdf should be initialized with CSS file
// deep clone, we need a completely independent copy:
$mpdf_sizeworker=unserialize(serialize($mpdf));
$mpdf_sizeworker->setX(0); 
$mpdf_sizeworker->setY(0); 
// Make sure $html has all block level elements closed
$mpdf_sizeworker->WriteHTML($html, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY, true, true); // init:true close:true
$html_width=$mpdf_sizeworker->x;
$html_height=$mpdf_sizeworker->y;
```